# Merging Two List with Same Properties into One List

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, merge

Below is one of my entities:

```
[Table("UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog")]
public partial class UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog : IEntity
{
    public int UserPaymentAccountHistoryLogID { get; set; }

    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserPaymentAccountID { get; set; }
    public bool ActionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogHistory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LogDetail { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPaymentAccount UserPaymentAccount { get; set; }
}
```

And this my other entity:

```
[Table("UserPaymentHistoryLog")]
public partial class UserPaymentHistoryLog : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int UserPaymentHistoryLogID { get; set; }

    public Guid UserPaymentAccountID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public bool TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogHistory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LogDetail { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, some of their properties are same. What I try to do is, I want to merge two lists which consist these two entities, into one list which consists below entity:

```
public class CardTransactionHistoryWM
{
    public bool ActionType { get; set; }
    public bool TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogHistory { get; set; }
    public string LogDetail { get; set; }
    public OrderWM Order { get; set; }
}
```

I run into solutions, suggest using `join` and `zip` linq queries but those same properties keep confusing me.

The important part is, if `UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog` and `UserPaymentHistoryLog` has the exact same date records, `CardTransactionHistoryWM` should publish one line, not two, for this date, and display both `UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog` and `UserPaymentHistoryLog` LogDetails.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well I wonder why cant one class extend the other here and then youll only have one type to concat. Otherwise Id use automapper to map to one class and concat

Comment: I assume you want a list of All objects in memory, in that case you can go with an abstract base class or an interface for both classes and from there you can create the list<interface> to add the objects.

Comment: I think I cannot achieve both of your suggestions as these entities are directly bound to database tables

Comment: *I think I cannot achieve both of your suggestions* -- Why not? You can map lists of both classes to lists of `CardTransactionHistoryWM` and concat those.

Answer (score 0):

If the join and/or zip methods are too complicated or hard to understand, another way to do it would be to extend your `CardTransactionHistoryWM` class to include:

1. A static `Parse` method that returns an instance of the class based on an instance of `UserPaymentHistoryLog`
2. A static `Parse` method that returns an instance of the class based on an instance of `UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog`
3. A `MergeWith` instance method that merges an existing instance with an instance of `UserPaymentHistoryLog`
4. A `MergeWith` instance method that merges an existing instance with an instance of `UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog`

For example:

```
public class CardTransactionHistoryWM
{
    public bool ActionType { get; set; }
    public bool TransactionType { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogHistory { get; set; }
    public string LogDetail { get; set; }
    public OrderWM Order { get; set; }

    public void MergeWith(UserPaymentHistoryLog uphl)
    {
        if (LogHistory != uphl.LogHistory)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot merge if LogHistory dates don't match");

        TransactionType = uphl.TransactionType;
        LogDetail = string.Concat(LogDetail, uphl.LogDetail);
    }

    public void MergeWith(UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog upahl)
    {
        if (LogHistory != upahl.LogHistory)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot merge if LogHistory dates don't match");

        ActionType = upahl.ActionType;
        LogDetail = string.Concat(LogDetail, upahl.LogDetail);
    }

    public static CardTransactionHistoryWM Parse(UserPaymentHistoryLog source)
    {
        return new CardTransactionHistoryWM
        {
            TransactionType = source.TransactionType,
            LogHistory = source.LogHistory,
            LogDetail = source.LogDetail
        };
    }

    public static CardTransactionHistoryWM Parse(UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog source)
    {
        return new CardTransactionHistoryWM
        {
            ActionType = source.ActionType,
            LogHistory = source.LogHistory,
            LogDetail = source.LogDetail
        };
    }
}
```

With these methods added, you can then use them when parsing your two lists to either create a new instance of the `CardTransactionHistoryWM` class or to merge with an existing instance if the dates match:

```
public static List<CardTransactionHistoryWM> Merge(
    List<UserPaymentAccountHistoryLog> userPaymentAccountHistoryLogs,
    List<UserPaymentHistoryLog> userPaymentHistoryLogs)
{
    var results = new List<CardTransactionHistoryWM>();

    foreach (var upahl in userPaymentAccountHistoryLogs)
    {
        var match = results.SingleOrDefault(cthwm => cthwm.LogHistory == upahl.LogHistory);

        if (match == null)
        {
            results.Add(CardTransactionHistoryWM.Parse(upahl));
        }
        else
        {
            match.MergeWith(upahl);
        }
    }

    foreach (var uphl in userPaymentHistoryLogs)
    {
        var match = results.SingleOrDefault(cthwm => cthwm.LogHistory == uphl.LogHistory);

        if (match == null)
        {
            results.Add(CardTransactionHistoryWM.Parse(uphl));
        }
        else
        {
            match.MergeWith(uphl);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```